# different element data types within numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Just like list in python where [1,"hello", {"python": 10}] it can have all different types within, can numpy array have this as well?

when numpyarray.dtype => dtype('float64') is it implying all elements are of type float?

Comment: Why do you want an array with mixed data types?  Why not stick with a list?

Comment: I just wanted to know. Since incoming data can be of many different types I wanted to know what happens when I convert it to numpy array

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> dtype : data-type, optional
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will
>   be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the
>   sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For
>   downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

So if you set dtype as float64, everything needs to be a float. You can mix types, but then you can't set it as a mismatching type. It will use a type that will fit all data, like a string for example in the case of `array(['1', 'Foo', '3.123'])`.

Comment: dtype for array([1, 1.2, "foo"]) give me "<U32". this implies all elements fall in dtype <U32? and what is "<U32" data type?

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @HaneulKim You're right, I forgot to actually write them down as strings. Edited the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use [numpy structured arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), each element of the array would be a "structure", and the fields of the structure can have different datatypes.

The answer to your second question is **yes**. When the `dtype` attribute shows a value of `float64`, it means each element is a `float64`